# Issue with AMD Drivers

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati

I recently made a linux box and installed 32bit Ubuntu 13.04 by accident, at that time the AMD drivers worked flawlessly. As soon as I installed the 64-bit version I began getting Super-User errors, I check the forum on it and it did not help me because I don't know what the Gnome menu is or how to access, please help me and forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What are these "Super-User" errors ? You have to provide more info about those errors. A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: I launch the .run file, it asks me for my password (never happened in 32bit), I enter in the password and a window pops up and says "You need to run this installer as the super-user." This is confusing to me because I am the main account on the computer.

Comment: p.s. this is amd's catalyst driver for my gpu: the R9 280x

Comment: I also don't know how to post pictures

Comment: I also Installed 13.10 64bit before and had the same problem and thought there was just no support because of how new it is

Comment: Here is your answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/286775/95393 Read it carefully.

Comment: K, will try strange though I mean its so new

Comment: It seems to be work, but at about 50% of the power out put I tested while in minecraft, 120-200+fps vs 50-60fps. Thanks though It will be enough for my needs at this moment

Comment: Seems to be resolved in the current drivers

Answer (score -1):

I have found out that all you need to do is force install from terminal. I feel so dumb *facepalm*.

Comment: Exactly how do I force a install? Can you be more detailed both in the answer and the question?

Comment: Sorry, my issue was that my amd catalyst drivers would not work so I ran it from terminal, then I found out that just running it made .log file that made the driver think there was an old driver there so it would not install over it.The only way I could install was to 'sudo /location of the file/drivername.run --force' which forced the .log to be deleted and the driver to be installed and then my driver worked, I have no Idea why I had a .log in there after deleting the driver in the first place

Comment: Don't use comments to explain to "me" but edit your answer/question to explain it better.